# What is ttk's tkinter default color style for MAC OSX

Tags: python, colors, tkinter, ttk

I'm looking for either the exact colour name for ttk frames or for a way to dynamically retrieve that information. My problem is that the tkinter

```
root = tk()
```

and

```
button = ttk.Button()
```

give me two different widget background colours. This was **not** an issue when I developed the GUI on **ubuntu linux**, but the colours are different when I tried to run the code on **MAC OSX 10.8.1**

I haven't been able to find any calls/attributes that would give me that information, and there are so many different colours it could be (white, light white, seashell white, etc...)

Anyone know these default colour names?

I'm using python 2.7.2, tkinter, ttk, MAC 10.8.1

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to get that information. The problem is, there may not be a single color for the background (it might be a slight gradient or pattern). If the problem is that the background of your app looks wrong there's a simple trick: place a ttk.Frame() widget over the entire root window, and then just code as usual. As long as the stacking level of the frame is low, all your other widgets will appear above it.

I use `place` for this, giving an x and y of zero and a relwidth and relheight of 1.0. Using `place` guarantees it would affect the use of `pack` or `grid` for all your other widgets.

Comment: I may have to consider looking at something like that. I'm trying to avoid having to make a lot of changes (it's a rather large project). It really just seems that the default background colour of ttk widgets is different than the default of the `tk()` root. I also never set any colours when I created the program, because all the defaults were matching up, until I ran it on a MAC.

Comment: It's a Mac, not MAC :-). You are correct, though: the backgrounds are different. Unless you have lots of toplevel windows, this should be a pretty simple fix.